# How to check if a booleanfield ina django modelform is true and add whatever it is true under to a list?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create an e-commerce site (CS50 Project 2) that allows the user to add a listing item to their watchlist. I have decided to use a Django's ModelForm with a BooleanField that corresponds with the WatchList model to do this.

I have created the form but i'm not sure how to check if it is true and save the listing to the WatchList model.

views.py

```py
def listing(request, id):
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    listing_price = listing.bid
    sellar = listing.user
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
 
    if watchlist_form == True:
        listing.add()

    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
            "auction_listing": listing,
            "form": comment_form,
            "comments": comment_obj,
            "bidForm": bid_form,
            "bids": bid_obj,
            "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
        })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": comment_form,
        "comments": comment_obj,
        "bidForm": bid_form,
        "bids": bid_obj,
        "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
    })
```

models.py

```py
class WatchList(models.Model):
    listing = models.ManyToManyField(Listings)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    add_to_watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Listings models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
    ("Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous"),
    ("Movies and Television", "Movies and Television"),
    ("Sports", "Sports"),
    ("Arts and Crafts", "Arts and Crafts"),
    ("Clothing", "Clothing"),
    ("Books", "Books"),
]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000000000, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create html element like check box or drop down selection

```
<label>Wishlist:</label><select  id="choice" name="wish" ><option value="" selected>Choose option</option><option value="True">yes</option><option value="False">no</option></select>
```

then send this selected value with `request` and use it with condition if its `Yes` then wishlist is `True` and vice versa

Comment: how do I add the listing to the WatchList model?

Comment: @skateb2020  you have to pass listing id in  `value = "listing_id"` in html and send it along with That BooleanField and use it for query like `WatchList.objects.create(id=listing_id,add_to_watchlist  = True or False)`

Comment: I have still not been able to save the listing to the WatchList model. I did not change the form to html but kept it as a django form. Your code in the previous comment did not work, and now this is the code I am trying to use: ```if watchlist_form.is_valid():
        a = WatchList.objects.get(listing=id).WatchList.add(listing)```. I am receiving this error: ```WatchList matching query does not exist.```. Do you know how to fix these problems? (I also added my Listings model so you would better understand the code.)

Comment: are you able to fetch all the details in request.POST from the frontend? If yes then make a simple create query like this
`WatchList.objects.create(listing_id=listing_id,user_id=request.user.id, add_to_watchlist=True or False)`
or connect with me on discord app username='JW#6954' because i cant give you a solution until i see exact problem.